# How to implement this Lock Screen feature on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I found an app called **LOCK SCREEN** in WP Store, here is the link:

[Lock Screen](http://www.windowsphone.com/zh-cn/store/app/lock-screen/f93c89f3-2136-4640-8f58-ecf86aba05b9)

Anyone knows how does the App do that? What API does it use?

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, you can update two items on the lock screen, the [notifications area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207048%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and the [background image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206968%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: He's asking how to actually cause the screen to lock, not what he can put on the lock screen.

Comment: Thanks all of you, I got the answer from forum.xda-developers.com, the developer used some restricted API.

Comment: Apologies, I saw lock screen and my eyes glazed over reading the link. No coffee. I did buy the app just to see what was going on. Pretty nifty, considering I don't think it is supposed to be possible.

Comment: For anyone curious, [here is a link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2594420) to xda where the dev is talking about getting through windows phone certification with an app that accesses a restricted api.